# How to create a Rmap (GPS file) with Java?

Tags: java, file, dictionary, gps

I need to create a ***.rmap** file from several images with Java. The problem is I cannot find any documentation on this file type.

Where can I find some documentation on GPS background images file? Does some librairy exists in Java?